# izPack disable debug Window

Tags: izpack

I'm using Izpack 5.1.2, and according to the [documentation](https://izpack.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/IZPACK/pages/491627/Getting+Debug+Information+from+Running+IzPack+Installers), the following is used to enable debugging information:

```
java -DDEBUG=true -jar installer.jar
java -DSTACKTRACE=true -jar installer.jar
java -DTRACE=true -jar installer.jar
```

And also:

```
<guiprefs>
   <modifier key="showDebugWindow" value="true"/>
</guiprefs>
```

As such, i assume to disable the debugging information, so the debug window wouldn't show, i would only need to change the above to false.

Unfortunately, even after setting all the above to *false*, when i execute the installer, the debug window still shows.

In order to create an exe for the java artifact, i'm wrapping it with launch4j, adding the  section to set the java variables to false:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>l4j-clui</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>launch4j</goal>
                    </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <headerType>console</headerType>
                            <jar>target/${installer-output-filename}.jar</jar>
                            <outfile>target/${installer-output-filename}.exe</outfile>
                            <classPath>
                                <mainClass>com.izforge.izpack.installer.bootstrap.Installer</mainClass>
                            </classPath>                            
                            <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
                            <jre>
                                <bundledJre64Bit>false</bundledJre64Bit>
                                <bundledJreAsFallback>false</bundledJreAsFallback>
                                <minVersion>1.8.0</minVersion>
                                <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
                                <runtimeBits>64</runtimeBits>
                                <opts>
                                    <opt>-DTRACE=false</opt>
                                    <opt>-DSTACKTRACE=false</opt>
                                    <opt>-DDEBUG=false</opt>
                                </opts>                             
                            </jre>
                            ....
```

I can't understand why after setting all the debug variables to false, the debug window still shows.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not on the IzPack configuration, but on the Launch4J configuration, as the *headerType* tag was incorrectly configured:

```
<headerType>console</headerType>
```

In order to disable the console Output i should have used the gui option:

```
<headerType>gui</headerType>
```